# What type of capacitor should i buy?

Tags: capacitor

I’m a software engineering student and working on a project with a microcontroller and building this [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/). My knowledge about hardware stuff is minimal.

I am having trouble with capacitors. There are several kind of capacitors with the same value. From the circuit I found (ex. Regulator 7805, Serial Programmer, etc) there are capacitors that show:

- just the value
- value with plus + and minus -
- value with voltage rating

I don’t know what kinds of capacitor I should choose and buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without specific examples (i.e. links to the circuits you found) it's hard to give an authoritative answer.

*In general*:

1. Capacitors specified with no polarity (no + and -) and no voltage rating are usually ceramic types, and common voltage ratings (25V, 50V) *should* be fine.
2. Capacitors that show polarity are polarized types - usually electrolytic, sometimes tantanlum. Substitution with ceramic or other types usually isn't possible as the capacitance needed may require many in parallel. Polarized capacitors in the tens of microfarads or higher are generally electrolytic. Lower values could be electrolytic or tanatalum.
3. A voltage rating is a helpful hint. Never place a cap with a lower voltage rating where a higher voltage rating is indicated.  A good guideline is to choose the capacitor with voltage rating, which is twice the nominal voltage across the capacitor in the circuit.  High voltage, small values (picofarads to a few nanofarads) are generally ceramic; high voltage with higher values (tens of nanofarads and up) are often metal film or polypropylene capacitors.
4. Capacitors that say X, Y, X# (i.e. X2) or Y# (i.e. Y1) are *safety-critical* and must be special ceramic or film capacitors that bear safety markings (UL, TUV, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Madmanguruman, i think i got the explanation for now. But I have a situation where building this [USBasp] (http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) . I'm focusing on the 100nF capacitor.<br/>
1. I buy from the nearest electronic store, telling them 100nF and they giving me a green polyster capacitor.<br/>2. The Official page of USBasp using a ceramic 100nF (so i buy again and using this 100nF ceramic).<br/>3. But this one is using a wima-capacitor [USBasp HowTo] (http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/usbasp_gr.rar). <br/>So i finally using like the official and it's work without knowing why.

Comment: A ceramic 100nF would be rather large. Generally speaking, caps measured in pF are ceramic, in nF are plastic film of one kind or another, small uF are tantalum or electro, and large uF are electro. It sounds like you've got the right part in there.

Comment: @EJP  The mechanical size of the cap depends on the voltage rating as much as on the capacitance value.  I have a 100nF (or 0.1uF) in 0402 package, which isn't rather large.

Comment: @DarrelG.  Have you got the circuit board from the kit, or are you building on a bread-board?

Comment: @EJP I just buy the 100nF ceramic without knowing the different with plastic film or tantalum or even electro [at shop] (http://sfe-electronics.com/index.php?id_product=191&controller=product)

Comment: @NickAlexeev i have limited time and money (university project) so i built it directly without breadboard but PCB (http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-A-Customized-Circuit-Board-Made-Easy) and buy the remaining stuff. Build it and just luckily works. [refer to] (http://www.ellution.com/2012/03/learn-to-make-usbasp-is-easy.html)

Comment: @EJP If you haven't already, research a bit about multilayer ceramic capacitors. They can be quite small even for through-hole versions and have 100s of nanofarads.